# Powershell Looping and Substring

Tags: powershell, loops, logging, dns

I am trying to scrub hundreds of DNS logs for analysis. I found Powershell code through online research that I am leveraging. However, the code only processes one file at a time. I would like to iterate the code over several files located in the same folder. In addition, I want to substring the filename of each DNS log to obtain the server name (first 10 characters of the file name).

I used Get-ChildItem to iterate over multiple files and I believe that is successful. However, I am stuck on how to get the Server name from the file and putting it in a column.

```
function Get-DNSDebugLog
{

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
      [Alias('Fullname')]
      [string] $DNSLog = 'StringMode')


    BEGIN { }

    PROCESS {

        $TheReverseRegExString='\(\d\)in-addr\(\d\)arpa\(\d\)'

        ReturnDNSLogLines -DNSLog $DNSLog | % {
                if ( $_ -match '^\d\d|^\d/\d' -AND $_ -notlike '*EVENT*' -AND $_ -notlike '* Note: *') {
                    $Date=$null
                    $Time=$null
                    $DateTime=$null
                    $Protocol=$null
                    $Client=$null
                    $SendReceive=$null
                    $QueryType=$null
                    $RecordType=$null
                    $Query=$null
                    $Result=$null

                    $Date=($_ -split ' ')[0]
                    $ServerName = $null
                    # Check log time format and set properties
                    if ($_ -match ':\d\d AM|:\d\d  PM') {
                        $Time=($_ -split ' ')[1,2] -join ' '
                        $Protocol=($_ -split ' ')[7]
                        $Client=($_ -split ' ')[9]
                        $SendReceive=($_ -split ' ')[8]
                        $RecordType=(($_ -split ']')[1] -split ' ')[1]
                        $Query=($_.ToString().Substring(110)) -replace '\s' -replace '\(\d?\d\)','.' -replace '^\.' -replace "\.$"
                        $Result=(((($_ -split '\[')[1]).ToString().Substring(9)) -split ']')[0] -replace ' '
                        $ServerName=@{N='First5Chars';E={$_.BaseName.SubString(0,5)}}
                    }
                    elseif ($_ -match '^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d \d\d:') {
                        $Date=$Date.Substring(0,4) + '-' + $Date.Substring(4,2) + '-' + $Date.Substring(6,2)
                        $Time=($_ -split ' ')[1] -join ' '
                        $Protocol=($_ -split ' ')[6]
                        $Client=($_ -split ' ')[8]
                        $SendReceive=($_ -split ' ')[7]
                        $RecordType=(($_ -split ']')[1] -split ' ')[1]
                        $Query=($_.ToString().Substring(110)) -replace '\s' -replace '\(\d?\d\)','.' -replace '^\.' -replace "\.$"
                        $Result=(((($_ -split '\[')[1]).ToString().Substring(9)) -split ']')[0] -replace ' '
                        $ServerName=@{N='First5Chars';E={$_.BaseName.SubString(0,5)}}
                    }
                    else {
                        $Time=($_ -split ' ')[1]
                        $Protocol=($_ -split ' ')[6]
                        $Client=($_ -split ' ')[8]
                        $SendReceive=($_ -split ' ')[7]
                        $RecordType=(($_ -split ']')[1] -split ' ')[1]
                        $Query=($_.ToString().Substring(110)) -replace '\s' -replace '\(\d?\d\)','.' -replace '^\.' -replace "\.$"
                        $Result=(((($_ -split '\[')[1]).ToString().Substring(9)) -split ']')[0] -replace ' '
                        $ServerName=@{N='First5Chars';E={$_.BaseName.SubString(0,5)}}
                    }

                    $DateTime=Get-Date("$Date $Time") -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'


                    if ($_ -match $TheReverseRegExString) {
                        $QueryType='Reverse'
                    }
                    else {
                        $QueryType='Forward'
                    }

                    $returnObj = New-Object System.Object
                    $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Date -Value $DateTime
                    $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name QueryType -Value $QueryType
                    $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Client -Value $Client
                    $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name SendReceive -Value $SendReceive
                    $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Protocol -Value $Protocol
                    $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name RecordType -Value $RecordType
                    $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Query -Value $Query
                    $returnObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Results -Value $Result

                    if ($returnObj.Query -ne $null) {
                        Write-Output $returnObj
                    }
                }
            }

    }

    END { }
}



function ReturnDNSLogLines
{
param(
$DNSLog)

$PathCorrect=try { Test-Path $DNSLog -ErrorAction Stop } catch { $false }

    if ($DNSLog -match '^\d\d|^\d/\d' -AND $DNSLog -notlike '*EVENT*' -AND $PathCorrect -ne $true) {
        $DNSLog
    }
    elseif ($PathCorrect -eq $true) {
        Get-Content $DNSLog | % { $_ }
    }
}

$DNSlogs = Get-ChildItem "C:/users/Desktop/*.log" |
foreach ($d in $DNSlogs):{
    $Servername = $DNSlogs[0]}


Get-DNSDebugLog -DNSLog "C:/users/Desktop/*.log" | Export-Csv .\ProperlyFormatedLog2.csv.
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or incorrect results? Also, it looks like the only relevant code for this question is `$DNSlogs = Get-ChildItem "C:/users/Desktop/*.log" |
foreach ($d in $DNSlogs):{
    $Servername = $DNSlogs[0]}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be the best approach, but this should work without changing your function code.

```
$DNSlogs = Get-ChildItem "C:/users/Desktop/*.log"
foreach ($d in $DNSlogs) {
    $Servername = $d.basename.substring(0,[math]::Min(10,$d.basename.length))
    Get-DNSDebugLog -DNSLog $d.FullName | Select *,@{n='ServerName';e={$ServerName}} | Export-Csv -Path '.\ProperlyFormatedLog2.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

I know you said you wanted the first 10 characters of the filename for the server name. I did add the `[Math]::Min()` function go grab all of the characters if their length is less than 10 just in case you have a short server name. The `.basename` property of the file object contains the filename excluding the extension.

I feel like a rewrite may be needed to do EVERYTHING you want, which includes parallel processing while getting the server name. I also see that your function sets `$ServerName`, but you never use it.